# avoid overlapping arrows in plantuml class diagrams

Tags: svg, graphviz, class-diagram, plantuml

I am using plantuml for creating the class diagrams along with arrows and messages on the arrows. It works perfect untill the diagram is huge. In large diagrams where there are multiple arrows and multiple classes, the arrows gets overlapped with each other hiding/overlapping the arrows and messages on it. Is there any property or way to avoid these overlapping? It will be OK even if the diagram size grows.
I read about -

```
overlap = false; 
splines = true;
```

properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967600/how-to-prevent-edges-in-graphviz-to-overlap-each-other), but I am not sure how to use it with PlantUML or SVG file.

Note : I am creating a SVG file from plantuml using java.

Comment: following and interested if there is an answer. have the same question for activities

Comment: Would love an answer for this, too. I have a diagram that is *almost* perfect, but a single arrow line overlaps an object. :(

Comment: This is a highly complicated topic and not for all circumstances it is possible to prevent crossing lines (see e.g. the well known problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem). I think `dot`  and `plantuml` triy the utmost but it is impossible to get everything right for larger diagrams.

Comment: I have heard it suggested that it may be best to consider graphviz a capable but belligerent teenager, and just accept what it does and be glad you did not have to do it. (then fix it in a svg editor)

Comment: This has a lot of upvotes, but there is no concrete example. OP, can you post something?